# error while trying to run MapReduce job using eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I am trying to run MapReduce jobs using hadoop-eclipse plugin with Eclipse Indigo, but I am getting the following error:

`Error: failure to login`

While looking for some help, I found there is a problem with Hadoop-0.20.203.0, so I tried Hadoop-0.20.205.0 as the issues are fixed in this version.

I am still facing the same problem. Am I missing something or making a mistake?

Comment: I don't know how we could tell if you were making a mistake or not.

Comment: I meant,there could be some modification that is required and I may be missing it.

Comment: I don't know how we could tell if there was some modification required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my poor English, as your question has no more detail, I guess that you meet the same problme as me, if so, the following link resolved my problem, pls. pay attention to step "4".

http://hi.baidu.com/wangyucao1989/blog/item/279cef87c4b37c34c75cc315.html

Sorry for that is a page in Chinese. It said the problem is because the file hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0.jar lost 5 files  "commons-configuration-1.6.jar , commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar , commons-lang-2.4.jar , jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar 和 jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar ". You should:
Extract the "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0.jar",
Add the 5 files into "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0\lib" , 
Modify "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF" (modify the Bundle-ClassPath).
Re 'jar' the package and replace the old "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0.jar".

The os the page referred is linux, my os is Win7.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help wanghongsheng..and there is absolutely no need to be sorry for anything..anyway i have to use java, not english, chinese or my native language.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for adding plugin u can just add the required libraries in eclipse and do your programming.
here is the list of library u will need. These files exists with the Apache hadoop distribution in lib folder.

- hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
- commons-configuration-1.6.jar